# Dynamic tar/archive creation in Mojolicious

Tags: perl, tar, mojolicious, caddy

I have a directory of uploaded files, and I want to the user to download all files as an archive/tar. This is what I have implemented so far:

```
get '/admin/downloadmedia' => sub {
    my $c = shift;

    my $tar = Mojo::Tar->new;

    my $cb = $tar->files( [ glob('../files/*') ] )->create;
    warn Dumper( $tar->files );
    my $drain;
    $drain = sub {
        my $me = shift;
        return $me->finish if ( $tar->is_complete );
        my $chunk = $cb->();

        $me->write( $chunk, $drain );
    };

    $c->res->content->headers->add( 'Content-Type',        'application/tar' );
    $c->res->content->headers->add( 'Content-Disposition', 'attachment;filename=Zahaan-Bday-Media.tar' );

    $c->$drain;
};
```

I am behind a proxy sever (Caddy).
Downloaded file is correctly identified as tar.

```
$ file Downloads/Zahaan-Bday-Media\ \(1\).tar                                                                                                                                                                              
Downloads/Zahaan-Bday-Media (1).tar: POSIX tar archive
```

But archive utility throws an error and is unable to open.
Unable to understand whats wrong.

Comment: *"But archive utility throws an error"* - What archive utility? What error?

Comment: Loading the archive ‘/home/pradeep/Downloads/Zahaan-Bday-Media (1).tar’ failed with the following error:
Could not load the archive because it contains ill-formed entries and might be a malicious archive.

Comment: <pre><code>$ tar -tf "Downloads/Zahaan-Bday-Media\ \(1\).tar"                                                                                                                                                                          
tar: Downloads/Zahaan-Bday-Media\\ \\(1\\).tar: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now</code></pre>

Comment: The last command simply complains about the file not existing, probably since you use both quotes around the name and also backspace for escaping at the same time and thus provide the wrong filename. As for your first command - unclear what archive program this is (might be ark).

Comment: Note also that it is a bad idea to create a tar archive with file names pointing outside the current directory (`../files/...`). Ark is known to not like this since this can be used in attacks - which might be the reason for the error you get.

Comment: Thanks, that worked somewhat, now Ark reads and lists the archive, but tar file doesn't contain all the files. Must be some issue with Mojo::Tar

Answer (score -1):

did you try to download the tar file directly (without going through the proxy) and see if it opens correctly.

You can try to debug it this way

```
use Mojo::Tar;

get '/admin/downloadmedia' => sub {
    my $c = shift;

    my $tar = Mojo::Tar->new;
    my $cb  = $tar->files([glob('../files/*')])->create;

    unless ($tar->is_complete) {
        $c->render(text => "error creating tar-archive: " . $tar->error, status => 500);
        return;
    }

    $c->res->content->headers->add('Content-Type',        'application/tar');
    $c->res->content->headers->add( 'Content-Disposition', 'attachment;filename=Zahaan-Bday-Media.tar' );


    my $drain;
    $drain = sub {
        my $me = shift;
        return $me->finish if ($tar->is_complete);
        my $chunk = $cb->();

        $me->write($chunk, $drain);
    };

    $c->$drain;
};
```

Comment: Yes tried without proxy, same issue. Also, how is your example going to help? Mojo::Tar creates a stream of the tar file, so $tar->is_complete will only return true when the full tar has been "streamed"